# Implement threadsafe service with locks on a per-key basis

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, reentrantlock

My goal is to implement a service which operates on Widgets, which have a property `name`. That service's operations consist of multiple smaller steps, which should be executed synchronously per `name`, meaning no two operations on widgets of the same name may be interweaved.

The easiest solution is to just lock those operations entirely, for example with EJBs like this:

```
@Singleton
public class WidgetService {
    @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
    public void doThing(Widget widget) {
        // many individual steps
    }
}
```

However, this would also mean that operations on widgets of different names cannot be executed in parallel, which massively impacts performance in my case. So my solution was to implement a per-name locking mechanism. The Lock itself looks roughly like this:

```
public class NameLock implements AutoCloseable {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, ReentrantReadWriteLock> globalLocks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final String name;

    private NameLock(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = globalLocks.computeIfAbsent(name, s -> new ReentrantReadWriteLock());
        lock.writeLock().lock();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = globalLocks.get(name);
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

and is used like this:

```
public class WidgetService {
    public void doThing(Widget widget) {
        try (NameLock lock = new NameLock(widget.getName())) {
            // many individual steps
        }
    }
}
```

However, this means that the `globalLocks` map gets populated with locks which never get cleaned up. I cannot simply call `globalLocks.remove(name)` in the close method, because due to parallelism another thread may already retrieved that lock and is blocked at the `lock()` method. Is there an elegant way I can achieve this in a threadsafe, non-memory leaking way?

I wrote a test for this, which should just finish fast without errors if the locking works as expected. This passes for my implementation, but still leaves the locks in the map behind:

```
@Test
public void lockMultiple() throws Exception {
    final int nThreads = 10;
    final int nTasks = 200;
    final Random random = new Random();

    final ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    final Function<Integer, Integer> func = i -> {
        try (NameLock lock = new NameLock("foo")) {
            // fuzzing
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));
        }
        return i;
    };
    final List<Future<Integer>> futures = IntStream.range(0, nTasks)
            .mapToObj(i -> (Callable<Integer>) () -> func.apply(i))
            .map(threads::submit)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
        final Integer i = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been suggesting Guava's [Striped](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) many times recently. Looks like a good fit here as well.

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I need, thanks!